# html автораспределение новостей по страницам

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, site

Вот допустим есть новостная страница. есть много новостей. как разбить эту страницу на подстраницы (ну тип первая страница вторая третья и тд...) и распределить новости автоматически по ним.
что б десять новостей на первой, следующие десять на второй и так далее....
главное что б при добавлении новой новости она появлялась в начале списка а последняя с этой страницы переходила на следующую и так далее.
как реализовать этот механизм? на чем? может кто-то знает какие-то статьи...
если есть идеи как избавится от такого механизма, тоже слушаю.
заранее спасибо!

Comment: Читайте про пагинацию (pagination), или если вы хотите избавиться от нее, можете использовать lazy-load. Но вот что-то конкретное сказать по вашему вопросу нельзя, так как вообще не известно, что у вас за архитектура приложения, добавьте код.

Comment: Спасибо, ты мне действительно очень помог. Но теперь появился другой вопрос 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/856338/jscroll-не-работает-на-телефоне