# jScroll не работает на телефоне

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, lazyloading

https://jscroll.com/
вот есть интересный плагин для lazy-load. на пк все отрабатывает четко. запускаю в chrome режим разработчика (смотрю как на мобильных версиях) все тоже четко. открываю сайт на телефоне(в chrome) - ничего толком не грузится. первые 5 сек еще может прогрузить а потом jquery будто вообще не откликается. но если положить телефон в спящий режим а потом снова включить - может прогрузить еще пару divов.
если открыть в opere то там вообще ничего кроме первых записей не прогружает.

p.s. на других страницах анимация связанная со скриптами на jquery отрабатывает четко

если кто шарит что делать или чем заменить jScroll пишите пож
заранее спасибо.

Comment: НАШЕЛ РЕШЕНИЕ
строчку похожую на эту (с такой функцией она там одна а названия переменных могут быть другие)  

iTotalHeight = Math.ceil(iTopHeight - innerTop + _$scroll.height() + iContainerTop);  

заменяем на  
  
iTotalHeight = Math.ceil(iTopHeight - innerTop + _$scroll.height() + 200 + iContainerTop);

Comment: PS решение выше только для chrome

Comment: для opera не пашет